# Is there a way to paste over more than one item at the same time?

Tags: r, rstudio, copy-paste

In RStudio when I copy 'age' to the clipboard and double click 'name' each mention of 'name' is highlighted. Is there a way to then paste age over all mentions of name at the same time?

So double click 'name' then click something else and every 'name' becomes age.

```
age

name
name
name
```

Comment: Refactoring a variable name is what you’re looking for

Comment: One can use find and replace. CTRL+F should do. This works in a script not console.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring the variable name is what you are looking for

Comment: It's actually "Rename in scope" in the `Code` menu.